# android pick random images?

Tags: java, android

How can i load a random image out of 2 ?

I tried this code

```
final Random rgenerator = new Random();
Integer [] mImageIds = 
 {
  R.drawable.mantrans,
  R.drawable.womentrans,
 };
 Integer q = mImageIds[rgenerator.nextInt(mImageIds.length)];
 gBall1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), q);
```

but it did not work...

Please help

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Also, you could just use `int`, there's no need to use `Integer` here.

Comment: David when i tried it all it did was produce the womentrans image

Comment: I think you were just unlucky! Try it a few more times, it seems like it should work.

Comment: pents your comment did not help.. Try what a few more times.. I'm asking for a code fix..

Comment: I mean run this code through many times to confirm that it is indeed not just unlucky that you kept seeing the same result. Because it seems like it should be OK.

Comment: i get same result... just the chick

Answer (score 1):

this is useful to you..

```
  /////*****Random numbers with out repetation*****//////
    final int[] imageViews = {
            R.id.imgview11, R.id.imgview12, R.id.imgview13  };

    final int[] images = {
            R.drawable.i1, R.drawable.i2, R.drawable.i3  };

            Random rng = new Random(); 
            List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>(maxNoOfImages);             
            for (int i = 0; i < maxNoOfImages; i++)  {               
                while(true)   {
                    Integer next = rng.nextInt(maxNoOfImages); 

                    if (!generated.contains(next))  {                           
                        ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(imageViews[i]);                                                  
                        iv.setImageResource(images[next]);

                            generated.add(next);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a too much for such a simple task. But I haven't really used the Random class. This is an alternative method.

```
ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ids.add(R.drawable.mantrans); 
ids.add(R.drawable.womentrans);

Collections.shuffle(ids);

gBall1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), ids.get(0));
```

You may need to add a bit more id's as getting random in 2 options might not seem much random like pents90 mentioned.

Comment: I've tested this code and it seems to work fine. Put this code in a simple java program and fill it with integers. And run it a couple of times, it will give you different values. Collections.shuffle has to be called every time before you access the value so that you get a random number.